If $A$ and $B$ are non-zero symmetric matrices, and $A = B^2$, prove that the eigenvalues of $A$ are non-negative?
I was doing this proof in my homework and got to a solution that I am unsure if is correct because I did not use the fact that they are symmetric:
First, I started with the definition by letting $λ$ be an eigenvalue of $B$ with the corresponding eigenvector $v$.
Hence $Bv = λv$
Then I did the following steps:
$Bv = λv$
$BBv = λBv$ (Multiply by $B$ on both sides, can move $λ$ to the outer part as it is a scalar)
$Av = λBv$ (As we know A = B^2)
$Av = λ(λv)$ (Substituting again with the initial equation I started with)
$Av = λ^2(v)$
Hence, we can see that all of the eigenvalues of $A$ are $λ^2$, meaning they are non-negative.
I don´t know if this proof is correct as I did not use the fact that A and B are both symmetric, so I´m curious if I got it right.

You mean nonzero or nonnegative

As written in the title, this is obviously false.  Recall that $0 = 0^2$

Once the statement is fixed to talk about non-negative reals (rather than non-zero), recall that real matrices might have complex eigenvalues.  If you let $\lambda$ just be any old eigenvalue of $B$ there is nothing that says that $\lambda^2$ is non-negative since $\lambda$ could have been complex and non-real.  It is only after recalling that symmetric real matrices necessarily have real eigenvalues that you can make this claim.

You'd need to know that all eigenvalues for $B$ are real, and then your proof would work. If $\lambda$ is complex, then $\lambda^2$ is not even necessarily real.

Please fix your title - the word "non-zero" makes the statement false, but your answer indicates you mean non-negative.

So the only problem is stating that eigenvalues are real numbers. Appart from that, is the proof correct?

The assumption of symmetricity assures us that the eigenvalues of B are real (by the spectral theorem).

There is a flaw with your logic. You begin with $\lambda$, an eigenvalue of $B$ and proved that $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. But what happens with the others eigenvalues of $A$, the ones that doesn't come from eigenvalues of $B$? If you want to prove something about eigenvalues of $A$ you need to begin by considering an eigenvalue of $A$.

@Nolord this is only true for real symmetric matrices. Any diagonal matrix with complex entries is a trivial counterexample.

Assume $A$ and $B$ only have real entries. Then, since they are symmetric, they can be diagonalized. Immediately we then see that all diagonal entries of $A$ are squares, hence positive. Note that the assumption of symmetry alone requires the entries to be real. If we want to extend the argument to complex valued matrices, they need to be hermitian instead.
